Multiples of an element of a Ring
If $r$ is an element of a ring $R$ and $n$ is a positive integer, does there exist an element $x \in R$ such that $rx=xr=r+r+\cdots+r$, where $r$ is summed $n$ times?
This is provable if $R$ has a multiplicative identity.

Not necessarily. In $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, there is no $x$ such that $2x = 2+2+2$ (or $2$).

Please do not answer questions in the comments, @ArturoMagidin.

This will fail in any nontrivial zero multiplication ring (rings, or as some would call them, "rngs" in which $xy=0$ for all $x$ and $y$). A simple example is $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, which is a 2-element ring, $\{0,2\}$, with $2\times 2= 2+2=0$.
Other examples which are not zero-multiplication rings can be found. Take for example the  ideal $(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, and consider it as a ring. Since the product of any two nonzero elements has degree at least $2$, there is not $r$ such that $rx = 2x$.
The condition may hold in rings that don't have a unity. Perhaps the simplest example is  to take
$$R = \bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{F}_2$$
where $\mathbb{F}_2$ is the field of two elements. This ring does not have a unity, but for every $x\in R$ there exist $y,z\in R$ such that $z\neq 0$, and $xy=x$, $xz=0$. The former gives you the equality $nx = x(ny)$, just as in rings with unity; the latter ensures there can be no unity in the ring.

@arturo-magidin provided a counterexample:

In $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ there is no $x$ such that $2x = 2 + 2 + 2$.

But I want to add that your statement is not only provable if the ring has a multiplicative identity, it's equivalent to requiring that the ring have a multiplicative identity. EDIT: this was wrong, we just need some solution to $rx = r$ for each $r$, but there may not be a multiplicative identity.
If there is some $x$ satisfying $r x = \underbrace{r + \cdots + r}_{n\text{ times}}$ for any combination of $n$ and $r$, then when $n = 1$ we have $r x = r$. Conversely, if $rx = r$ for some $x$, then $r(\underbrace{x + \cdots + x}_{n\text{ times}}) = ry = \underbrace{r + 
\cdots + r}_{n\text{ times}}$.
We just have to show $r_i x = r_i$ for any other choice of $r_i \in R$. Note that if $r_1 x= r_1$, then $r_2 r_1 x = r_2 r_1$, and also $(r_1 + r_1 + \cdots) x = r_1 x + \cdots = r_1 + \cdots$. So multiplication by $x$ has the same effect on sums and multiples as it does on the original $r_1$, and in fact it has the same effect on every element of $R$. Thus the statement holds if and only if $R$ has a multiplicative identity.

"and in fact has the same effect on every element of $R$." That assertion is unjustified. In fact, your claim is false. For example, in the ring of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself that have compact support, for every $f$ there is a $g$ such that $fg=f$, but the ring does not have a unity, since for every $f$ there exists $h\neq 0$ such that $fh=0$.

ah you are right, I started to realize that oversight just after I posted but didn't see that it was false

Another, possibly easier, counterexample is a direct sum of infinitely many rings with unity.
